# Boxplot with intervals based on timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

I have  the following similar dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import random

dikt={'Date': pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=1500, freq="5T"),
      'Snd': [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(1500)]}
df=pd.DataFrame(dikt)
```

what i want is to create is a plot which consists of a group of boxplots which every boxplot is a time interval of 3H

Every plot symbolizes a month

Any thoughts about how i can do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) to bin your dates per groups of x hours and [`dt.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) to only retain the time component, then [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.catplot(data=df.assign(group=df['Date'].dt.floor('3h').dt.time),
            x='group', y='Snd', kind='box')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i tried the solution but the thing is that at the x axis i get tons of tick labels and extremely many boxplots while is should have about 8 boxplots per plot @mozway

Comment: You will get 8 box plots **per day**. If you want to aggregate the days together, use `group=df['Date'].dt.floor('12h').dt.time`

Comment: i changed it as you said with the only alternation at dt.floor('3h') and it worked. Thank you very much for your assistance but if you have the time care to explain me the logic of the code here? @mozway

Comment: I updated the plot and added the documentation link for `dt.time` that keeps the time component without the date (making it possible to group by time irrespective of the date)